# Wrapping text in HTML such that the next line becomes longer

Tags: html, css, word-wrap

I am using captions on images in my website. The captions are in the bottom, and what I don't like is that when a caption is long, (the maximum is 2 lines in my case) the text wraps in such a way that I have a long first line and a short second line.

I don't like this:

```
"aaaaa aaaa aaaa aaaa
 aaaa "
```

I am trying to get something like this:

```
"aaaaa
 aaaa aaaa aaaa aaaa"
```

Any suggestions how I would achieve this kind of wrapping with CSS?

Comment: They look the same in the post, please edit your original question to show the new line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use HTML5 syntax to deal with this issue.

The `<br>. or <br/>` element designates an opportunity where content *may* wrap to maintain legibility.  Keep in mind this is HTML5 only.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is a problem for css. you need to do some pre or post processing on the string using javascript or c# or whatever server language you are using. you have to calculate where you want the breaks based on string size and add `<br/>` tag or possibly the newline character.